# Split a list into X evenly sized chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to split a list of integers into `nbChunks` chunks that all have the sum indicated in parameters(`max`).

The function should be like:

```
def split(list, nbChunks, max):
```

and the result of `split([25,5,10,13,7,30],3,30)`

would be like `[[10,7,13],[30],[25,5]]` (I don't care about the order of the numbers).

I've already tried it by sorting a long list, but never get the same sum.
If you have any idea, feel free to let me know.

Here is my current version:

```
def dispatchToServers(liste, nbServers, max):
    liste.sort(reverse = True) 
    output = []
    for server in range(nbServers):
        contentOfServer = []
        for element in liste:
            if canAdd(element, contentOfServer,max):
                contentOfServer.append(element)
                liste.remove(element)
        output.append(contentOfServer)
    return output

def canAdd(element, serverContent,max):
    if sum(serverContent, element) > max:
        return False
    else:
        return True
```

Comment: Please edit in the code of what you already tried, even if it's a bad first attempt

Comment: ok, but the code is pretty long

Comment: What do you do with the chunks that couldn't sum up to max?

Comment: there is necessarily a combination to find

Comment: This is somewhat related to the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem).

Comment: This is a complex mathematical problem, so I propose you to go first to https://math.stackexchange.com/, then come back and implement the solution into a code.

Comment: @GetRept did that answer the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works by looking at all the possible arrangements of the data using the `permutations` function

```py
from itertools import permutations

def split_chunks(data, nb_chunks, desired_max):
    for ordering in permutations(data):
        groups = []
        group = []
        group_total = 0
        found = True
        for x in ordering:
            group.append(x)
            group_total += x
            if len(group) > nb_chunks or group_total > desired_max:
                found = False
                break
            elif(group_total == desired_max):
                groups.append(group)
                group = []
                group_total = 0

        if found:
            return groups

    return None        

split_chunks([25,5,10,13,7,30], 3, 30)
```